# When I put a rectangle in a fmx memo I can not write in the memo

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am writing a small fmx program where I need to color a memofield and I have tried to use a style do this by adding a rectangle to the background.content. But when I do this I can no longer write text in the memo field at runtime.

I will be very happy if somebody can help me with that problem.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Can you show the code you used for this? It would make it a lot easier for us to help you track it down.  Thanks. :)

Comment: Hello - I just did find the solution for the problem. The problem was that HitTest was set to true - after I did set it to false all did work perfect.